# Thread stop and restart

Tags: android, multithreading

I have issues as follows:

1. I am working with threads in android and I want to run a thread when
   the activity starts. After a condition again I need to start the
   same thread in the same activity.
2. I searched so many sites but all say that I need to make instance of
   the same thread and I did it also. But of no help. Can anyone help?

Comment: what does the background task need to do? Can you be a bit more specific? there are several threading models in Android that cater for different types of tasks, e.g. using services, handlers or asynctasks are all viable ways of doing threaded work outside of your UI. Do you really need to keep the same thread, or are you really just trying to perform the same work each time in the background?

Answer (score 1):

You can't restart a thread. The closest you can come is to make the thread pause somehow (e.g. wait on a monitor) and then resume it later (e.g. by notifying that monitor). But once a thread has actually *stopped*, it can't be restarted.

Answer (score 1):

**i think you need a countdownTimer, which working as loop**

```
public void looper(final MediaPlayer secAudio) {
    try
    {
    tns_DCounter = new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            try
            {
            mPlayer.start();
            }catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            try
            {
            secAudio.start();
            tns_DCounter2 = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    looper(secAudio);
                }

            };
            tns_DCounter2.start();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    };
    tns_DCounter.start();
    }catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never down multithreading in andriod land but from what you described you need to have a loop with associated blocking mechanisms.  Look at [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) sight to get an overview of multithreading.